# Java Python Message Signature and Verification

Tags: java, python, compatibility, digital-signature, pycrypto

My server is coded in Python and I am making a java client for this server.

I am Signing a message(data) using:

```
public static byte[] Sign(PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] data) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Signing the key inside RSACrypto#Sign");
        Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");

        SecureRandom secureRandom =null;
        dsa.initSign(privateKey,secureRandom);
        dsa.update(data);
        return dsa.sign();
}
```

This returns a byteArray(named signed_data) , now I am encoding this signature using Base64.encodeBase64 and converting the byteArray(named my_byte_array) so formed into string using :

```
String str = new String(my_byte_array)
```

and sending this string to Server.

On server side, I receive this string , then Server verifies the signature using:

```
publicKey.verify(str(data), (long(base64.b64decode(my_byte_array)),))
```

using library http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.html

when I try to print my_byte_array on both side they are same, and so is signed_data and base64.b64decode(my_byte_array)

but I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '\x8b\xa1\xbb\x19fO\xea\xe7\xa4B\xd4\xd2\xa1\xe3\xb9\xd0\x89n\xa2\xfe\xb5\xedsL\x02\xba\xad\x12!qjp\x0c%+Z\t\xa7\x12\x08\x90\xfaTk\xca\xd0\xae\xd8\xa9\xfa\xbb]>9\x1c\x80\xd0
```

As far as I can think, this error is arising because Java signs the message into byte and python expects it to be in Long.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have actually 2 problems.

The first one is that - according to the [Java Cryptograpy Architecture API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html#AppA) - the *SHA1withRSA* algorithm involves PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. At the Python side, you must use the same padding scheme to verify the signature; that can be achieved with PyCrypto's PKCS#1 v1.5 signature module ([Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5-module.html)).

The second problem is the one you point out: the `verify` method of an RSA PyCrypto object
oddly requires the signature to be encoded as an integer. However, by using the module I mentioned above, the problem will go away, since it accepts byte strings.

Comment: is there any way to achieve this with NoPadding, on both Java and Python side ?

Comment: @d34th4ck3r There is a way, but padding is what makes an RSA signature secure, so it should always be used.

Comment: Thanks, but on trying your method, verification always leads to false :(, Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/3036062

Comment: @d34th4ck3r It would help if your examples included the public key the signature and the sample data.

Comment: I isolated this part of my code , on running it in pure java it seems to work fine, but when I am running the same code in android it always returns false.

Comment: Gingerbread bug [#18566](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18566) could be relevant.